# How to enforce run Once Only Controller in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I'm a newcomer to Jmeter and want to be able to run some setup requests once only, in which some variables are setup, before I then run a set of further requests for as many users as I set in the Number of Users Thread Group.  These users are passed the variables created in the Once Only Controller.

I've inherited a script as follows, using a Once Only Controller:

[image: Script]

If I set the Number of Threads as 10 to ramp up to 10 in one second and run for one minute, I expect the number of Samples (requests) made in the Once Only Controller to show as 1.  I only want these requests to run once then subsequent requests to use the setup data.

Why then, when I run, do I see the samples as 10 in the requests that are set in the Once Only Controller:

[image: aggregate report]

Bear in mind there may be some fundamental misunderstandings given my I'm a newcomer to Jmeter.

I found the setUp Thread Group Controller which seems to be what I need.  However, this does not seem to pass variables extracted using the JSON extractor into the next Thread Group 'Load Test'

[image: setUp Thread Group]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [Once Only Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)  for running specific samplers for every thread

> The Once Only Logic Controller tells JMeter to process the controller(s) inside it only **once per Thread**

You can add samplers to [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) so it'll be executed **once before test**

> execute before the test proceeds to the executing of regular Thread Groups.

- Note keep its default (especially Number of Threads = 1)

Comment: thank you.  I found the setUp Thread Group and that see,s to be what I need. However, when placed in another Thread Group (see amended question and screenshot), it no longer passes the variables to the subsequent tests in the Load Test group

Comment: @Steerpike you need to copy variable to JMeter properties e.g. using JSR223 Sampler: `props.put("varName", vars.get("varName"));` and then get it using `${__P(varName)}`

Comment: I am copying using post-processor; Json Extractor and storing variables this way.  Once I use setUp ThreadGroup it is no longer passing the variables.  If I use a Once Only Controller under the same Thread Group then it works

Answer (score 0):

As per [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) documentation:

> The Once Only Logic Controller tells JMeter to process the controller(s) inside it only once per Thread, and pass over any requests under it during further iterations through the test plan.

So each your Thread will execute Once Only Controller's children only once, no matter how many loops your thread group will have.

As you have 10 threads each of 10 threads will execute the requests once.

If you want to execute the request by only one thread, no matter how many requests are in the Thread Group - I would recommend going for [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) instead

1. Substitute Once Only Controller with an If Controller
2. Use the following condition:

   ```
   ${__groovy(ctx.getThreadNum() == 0 &&  vars.getIteration() == 1,)}
   ```